# Python unicode and list

Tags: python, t-sql, python-2.7

I am currently python learning. I'm working on an email script. Sending the mail goes well, I just want to add data to the mail which stands in my database. This he does, he just gives it as one long list again. like:

```
[(u'Test test', ), (u'i', ), (u'k', ), (u'b', ), (u'e', ), (u'n', ), (u'j', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', )]
```

He also gives the string as: uTEXT instead of TEXT

On several sites I've already looked at how to encode etc, I just do not get that working. How do I get this working? Probably it's something very simple for most of you.

I would also like to display the values from my list below and solve. Without the list of characters -> (['TEXT'])

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
import datetime
import time
import locale
import pyodbc

# DB
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=local;Integrated Security=SSPI;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select recordname from tablename where cast(Date as date) = cast(getdate() as date)");
row = cursor.fetchall()

datum = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%d-%w")

# Datum notatie
date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)).strftime("%d-%w-%Y")

# SMTP connectie
server = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 587

# login G-mail
login = "x"
password = "x"

# Mail instellingen + onderwerp en berichttekst
sender = "name"
recipient = "email"
subject = "subject" 

for rows in row:   
    print rows

message = "text" + str(rows) + "text"

headers = ["From: " + sender,
           "Subject: " + subject + " " +  date,
           "To: " + recipient,]

headers = "\r\n".join(headers)

session = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)

session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.ehlo
session.login(login, password)

session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + message)
session.quit()
```

---

The result of my query and rows is this, I will see this in my mail:

```
[(u'Test test', ), (u'i', ), (u'k', ), (u'b', ), (u'e', ), (u'n', ), (u'j', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', )]
```

I've tried things like:

```
message = "text" + str(rows.encode('ascii') + "text
```

or:

```
 [(rows[0].encode("utf-8"),) for rows in row]:   
        print rows
```

### For all those things I will get an error. I think my way of convert data is not good. Or that I do not at the right time applicable.

The result of my query and rows is this, I will see this in my mail:

```
[(u'Test test', ), (u'i', ), (u'k', ), (u'b', ), (u'e', ), (u'n', ), (u'j', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', )]
```

I've tried things like:

```
message = "text" + str(rows.encode('ascii') + "text
```

or:

```
 [(rows[0].encode("utf-8"),) for rows in row]:   
        print rows
```

For all those things I will get an error. I think my way of convert data is not good. Or that I do not at the right time applicable.

Comment: It sounds like the email stuff isn't relevant to your question. Can you construct a minimal example that demonstrates the problem? E.g. is the 'problem' that when you select data from the DB you get unicode instead of string objects?

Comment: A example of the problem I did:
[(u'Test test', ), (u'i', ), (u'k', ), (u'b', ), (u'e', ), (u'n', ), (u'j', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', )]

The problem is what you say, I get unicode instead of string objects

Comment: To convert unicode objects into string objects you need to use an encoding. You said "On several sites I've already looked at how to encode etc, I just do not get that working. How do I get this working?" What exactly have you tried? Please post the code!

Answer (score 0):

If your text only contains normal characters, you can just use `str.decode`:

```
>>> a=u"text"
>>> a
u'text'
>>> a.encode()  # equivalent to a.encode("utf-8")
'text'
```

And do that for each element in your list:

```
>>> l=[(u'Test test', ), (u'i', ), (u'k', ), (u'b', ), (u'e', ), (u'n', ), (u'j', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', ), (u'x', )]
>>> [(i[0].encode(),) for i in l]
[('Test test',), ('i',), ('k',), ('b',), ('e',), ('n',), ('j',), ('x',), ('x',), ('x',), ('x',), ('x',), ('x',), ('x',)]
```

`utf-8` is a good option, as it covers pretty much everything, but you can decode as `ascii` instead:

```
>>> a.encode("ascii")
'text'
```

If your text contains non-ascii characters, you may have to give an `errors` option to encode, such as `ignore` (which skips unhandleable characters):

```
>>> a=u"The number is π"
>>> a
u'The number is \u03c0'
>>> a.encode("ascii")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u03c0' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> a.encode("ascii", errors="ignore")
'The number is '
```

See the Python 2 [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for more examples.